# Parsing date in from string in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-format

Hi so I do understand there are many threads out here regarding this and ive been through many of them I'm not able to grasp the whole date format thing so here I am seeking your help :)

I've got a json object giving me this date "2014-01-10T02:01:42.657Z" and I have no idea what sort of format that is. I do know its a datetime from mssql database and I wish to parse this in java for which I'm using this code.

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date result = null;
        try {
            result = df.parse(last_active);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.i("Date Parser problem (Friend.java): ", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        Log.i("Date: ", result.toString());
```

I do understand that the "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is the wrong format to parse this date with but I am not able to find the right type of format string to format the following date.

"2014-01-10T02:01:42.657Z"

I appreciate your help :)

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what T and Z are supposed to mean here, but ust convert it to a format you know then parse.

Comment: That is the thing that is throwing me off as well, I've tried similar formats but the T and Z may be variable may not be its very weird.

Comment: It's the internationally standardized date format (ISO 8601). The T is the separator between date and time. The Z at the end indicates the UTC+0 timezone.

Comment: T is used to separate the date from the time, and Z is used to denote that the time is in UTC

Comment: This is an ISO 8601 format date.  The T shows you where the date ends and the time starts.  The Z tells you time timezone is UTC.  Google for 'Parsing ISO 8601 dates in Java' for more info.

Comment: ISO 8601  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 4):

This is simply a standard ISO-formatted date. The `T` in the middle is simply a separator, and the Z at the end means "UTC".

To parse it, simply use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX` as the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

Comment: The Z is relevant. It indicates that the date has been transformed to a String using the UTC timezone.

Comment: No need to parse that string in Joda-Time. Simply pass the string to a `DateTime` constructor. Joda-Time uses the ISO 8601 standard for its defaults. DateTime will automatically parse a valid ISO string.

Answer (score 1):

## ISO 8601

That string is in standard format, as defined by ISO 8601. In various protocols, this format is gradually [replacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) the silly [formats of yesteryear](http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/) such as `Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT`.

## Avoid java.util.Date/Calendar

The bundled classes java.util.Date and .Calendar are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. With the arrival of the [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8, they are practically deprecated. If you cannot go to Java 8, use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (which inspired java.time).

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library (third-party, open-source, free-of-cost) uses ISO 8601 for its defaults. So the Joda-Time class [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) automatically parses such strings.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-01-10T02:01:42.657Z" );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-01-09T18:01:42.657-08:00
```

### Time Zone

Notice Joda-Time applied my JVM’s default time zone thereby adjusting the time appropriately. If you wish to keep the DateTime object in UTC, pass a [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object in that constructor.

```
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-01-10T02:01:42.657Z", DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-01-10T02:01:42.657Z
```

## java.time

The [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) also uses ISO 8601 for its defaults, and automatically parses such standard strings.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2014-01-10T02:01:42.657Z" );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "instant: " + instant );
```

When run…

```
instant: 2014-01-10T02:01:42.657Z
```